# Modifying JavaFX periodically added object

Tags: java, javafx

I have a lot of objects that are periodically added to the scene via `PauseTranition`, and I want them to fade out by the time , how to achieve such thing , or how to modify a property of an object
that I do not have a reference for in general ?

Comment: Have a look at [timeline animations](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Timeline.html).

Comment: That answered my question!

Answer (score 2):

I found this helpful : [TimeLine (JavaFX 11)](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Timeline.html)

All in all : you need to include a `Timeline` inside the `PauseTransition` (or any other thread) and update the property you want to change from the head object ,
this code shows how to update the opacity of a line:

```
Line line = new Line(x1,y1,x2,y2);
   double timeBetweenEachUpdate = .1d;//seconds
 PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(timeBetweenEachUpdate));
    pt.setOnFinished((e) ->{
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    double fadeTime=1000.0d;//ms
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(fadeTime)),
  //here you can put any property , any value you want it to change to
   new KeyValue(line.opacityProperty(),0));
   timeline.play(); 
  pt.playFromStart();
});
 pt.play();
```